# Creating a form with jquery. Cannot append <br> after input element

Tags: jquery, forms, input, authentication, line-breaks

Here is the HTML version form I need to create using jquery...

```
<form id="loginForm" class="loginLabel" action="login/login.php" method="post">
    Username : <input type="text" name="Username" ><br>
    Password : <input type="password" name="Password" ><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="login_Submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

And here is the jquery I have written for it...

```
    var loginForm = document.createElement("form");

    var userInput = document.createElement("input");
        $(userInput).attr("id", "userInput")
                   .attr("type", "text")
                   .attr("name", "Username");

    var br = document.createElement('br');

    var passInput = document.createElement("input");
        $(passInput).attr("id", "passInput")
                   .attr("type", "text")
                   .attr("name", "Password");

    $(loginForm).attr("id","loginForm" )
            .attr("class", "loginLabel")
            .text("Username : ")
            .append(userInput)
            .append(br)
            .text("Password : ")
            .append(passInput);

    $(loginWrapper).append(loginForm);
```

Unfortunately, jquery overwrites the username input (userInput) with the password input (passInput). I checked the CSS and there is plenty of room to go around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) overwrites the entire content of the element, use `.append()` instead of `.text()`

```
$(loginForm).attr("id","loginForm" )
        .attr("class", "loginLabel")
        .append("Username : ")
        .append(userInput)
        .append(br)
        .append("Password : ")
        .append(passInput);
```

Answer (score 4):

Because text function will replace all the things in the DOM Node with new value.

Why not just use string concatenation:

```
<div id="loginWrapper"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script>
var html = 
    '<form id="loginForm" class="loginLabel" action="login/login.php" method="post">' + 
    'Username : <input type="text" name="Username" ><br>' + 
    'Password : <input type="password" name="Password" ><br>' + 
    '<input type="Submit" name="login_Submit" value="Login">';
$("#loginWrapper").append($(html));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Musa is correct `.text()` will overwrite, to get around this you can use `document.createTextNode(data);` to create a textNode to append these to your form.

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QDpsP/9/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode